# Access session in .js File where these session is created in .java Servlet File

Tags: java, javascript, session, servlets

In one of my webapp's servlet, I put some data in the user's `HttpSession` (see code below).

How can I retrieve this value on the client side, to use it in an already-existing JS method ?

```
// initialServlet.java

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
int a=4;
session.setAttribute("object", a);
```

Comment: 1) Please specify what project do you need this in.
2) Where are you running your .js file? Is it in web browser? Please note, that the data stored in session is stored on your web server, not in a client, where JS usually runs and cannost access the session on your server.
Basically what you're asking is how to serve beverages on a transatlantic flight from the airport the flight started.

Comment: Are you using jsp/servlet where the js file is imported?